# How to pass value of one TextView to another TextView in different Activity

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to pass object from one activity to another in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

I have two activities `Activity 1` and `Activity 2`. For these two activities, I have two XML layout 1.xml and 2.xml. In 1.xml I have a `Button` and in 2.xml I have `TextView`. So what I want is on click of `Button` which is on the first activity I want to open the 2nd activity and also want to display the text shown in `Button` on the `Textview` present in Activity2. I mean to say that suppose the text in the `Button` is "ADD" then this text will be displayed in `TextView`.

Note: `Button` is on Activity1 and `TextView` is on Activity2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[INTENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) Use `Intent` to pass data, `putExtra()` will allow you to put data

**ActivityA**

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, Activityb.class);
myIntent.putExtra("key", "value");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

**ActivityB**

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent(); // this is just for example purpose
myIntent.getExtra("key");
```

Comment: If i want to pass Date as value instead of string then how that can be done

Comment: Use date as String by the help of dateformatter.

Answer (score 2):

try this using Intent:

**In Activity 1 on Button Click:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activityone.class, Activitytwo.class);   
intent.putExtra("value2","world");  
startActivity(intent);
```

**In Activity 2:**

```
@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    String value1 = super.getIntent().getExtras().getString("value1");  
    myTextView.setText("value1: " + value1 + ");  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First Activity -

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String passingdata = textview.getText().toString();
                        Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putString("Key", passingdata);
                        i.putExtras(b);
                        startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Second Activity -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String receivingdata = b.getStringExtra("Key");
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondtext);
    tv.setText(receivingdata);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While starting new activity in your button click write below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("TextValue", text1.getText().toString());
intent.setClass(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your Activity2 in `onCreate()`

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("TextValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put extra parameters on your intent. Watch [this article](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html).