# I want a make button visible by a value in TextView

Tags: android, textview

So kinda fresh on android but i have a problem. I got 2 Activities one where you click and get points in a TextView and the sum/value in the TextView get sent to the other Activity. In the second Activity i want to have a Button that gets visible if you have the exact or above value/sum in the TextView

Comment: you just want and want you didn't even try this is not a code writing service

Comment: Please add a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) of an exact problem that you are having.

Comment: Mr.Patel... i have tried looking trough here and other sites to find some help on what i needed. but i was still stuck, sometimes you get stuck and need a point in the right direction..

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to pass the value from one activity to another. You can achieve this by using an intent to pass the value you want. Also, this question has already been made, you can find more details in the link:

[How to pass value of one TextView to another TextView in different Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023694/how-to-pass-value-of-one-textview-to-another-textview-in-different-activity)

To make the button visible according to your needs,in the onCreate method from your second activity you can use:

```
if (value >= 50) {
    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
} else {
    button.setVisibility(View.GONE)
}
```

Comment: The value I have passed, the thing I can't figure is how I will make a button visible by getting the value in the textview. As example if the Textview gets a value of 50 then it should be visible. Under 50 it should be invisible

Comment: Thank you! I will try that :)

Answer (score 0):

For this do this code in Activity A:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("sum","30");
startActivity(intent);
```

then do this in the second ActivityB:

```
if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null){
String sum = getIntent().getStringExtra("sun");
if(Integer.parse(sum)>number){
button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Thank you will try with that!! :) :)

Comment: Yeah sure and let me know buddy if it doesn't work then will try something else.